# Samba Share - MS Excel when saving "can't access the file, there are several possible reasons"

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have a weird problem in my samba 3.5.4 share on Ubuntu 10.10. I have one share definition for 3 client (A,B,C) This share contain some excel file which having a lot of formula and linked each other. Client A accesses the file with libre office (ubuntu), client B access with WinXP & MS Office 2003, The write and read process working successfuly on Both of them.

The problem occurs when client C accesses the same file with MS Excel 2003 (windows xp). This message box appears when he saves the file:

```
Microsoft office excel cannot access the \\192.168.1.23\myshare\
There are several possible reasons: 

     - The File ort path does not exist The file is being used by another program. 
     - The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a
     - Currently open workbooks.
```

I have tried the solution presented in [KB291204](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291204), but it didn't work.
Below is my share definition :

```
[brainshare]
comment = brainshare
path = /opt/brainshare/
valid users = @brainshare
force group = brainshare
read only = No
create mask = 0775
veto files = /*.scr/*.eml/thumbs.com/
```

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The solution came from samba@list.samba.org

```
 Add this line to your share definition :
 # On 3 July 2012 13:11, Daniel Müller <mueller@tropenklinik.de> wrote:
     directory mask=2770
     force directory mode=2770
     create mask = 2770
     force create mode=2770
     force security mode=2770
     force directory security mode=2770
     force group= yourgroup
 # Give the directory the sticky bit for the group
```