# Samba 4 vs MS Office - Error accessing the file for saving, open and read works

Tags: samba, centos6, network-share, microsoft-office-2010, samba4

**Description**

I am struggling with a rather old (well-known) issue using the latest samba 4 suite. The MS Office 2010 products refuse to save a new (or modified) file on the samba share and display a message of the form:

*"There was an error accessing the file \sambashare\smbtest\testfile.pptx".*

This particular issue persists only with MS Office 2010 files (docx, pptx, xlsx). Opening and reading the files works just fine, but when it comes to modifying or saving a new file, it doesn't work. Please note that ALL the other file types, including older MS Office products (eg. MS Office 2003) work just fine.

**Environment**

OS (server): CentOS release 6.2 (Final) --
OS (client): Windows 7 --
Samba version: samba-4.1.11

**Other similar cases:**

a) [Samba Share - MS Excel when saving "can't access the file, there are several possible reasons"](https://serverfault.com/questions/404249/samba-share-ms-excel-when-saving-cant-access-the-file-there-are-several-pos)

b) https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2011-December/165327.html

I have read lots of "resolved" cases with such kind of error but they all use older samba versions (3.*). The solutions provided to these cases don't work for the new samba version as some of the parameters were deprecated. I was hoping that this issue would have been resolved in samba 4 but it actually did not.

**Configuration**

Also I performed a series of tests by changing the smb.conf file. Here is what I currently have at the moment.

```
[smbtest]
comment = samba test workspace
path = /sambashare/smbtest
valid users = @g-staff
force group = g-staff
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
directory mask = 2770
force directory mode = 2770
create mask = 2775
force create mode = 2775
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support came from one of the Samba developers.

It seems like this problem was caused by my current IBM GPFS (network filesystem) configuration and not Samba.

**Resolving the problem**

The following 2 workarounds are available:

A) Apply "special" settings:

For GPFS 1.3.1.0 or higher -> enable GPFS setting for file rename using SMB2 access:

1. Using SSH, connect to the active management node as the 'root' user.
2. Run the following command to set the cifsBypassShareLocksOnRename flag:

> ```
> [root@gpfsmngtserver ~]# mmchconfig cifsBypassShareLocksOnRename=yes -i
> mmchconfig: Command successfully completed
> mmchconfig: Propagating the cluster configuration data to all affected nodes. This is an asynchronous process.
> ```

3. Verify the settings:

> ```
> [root@gpfsmngtserver ~]# mmfsadm dump config |grep -i cifs
> cifsBypassShareLocksOnRename 1    <---- check that this is now set to 1
> cifsBypassTraversalChecking 0
> ```

No reconnect of network drives or reboot of clients is required.

Note: Support for SMB2 will automatically be re-enabled when an upgrade has been applied.
Please check and reapply any workarounds that may be needed on the upgraded release, especially if a workaround had been applied prior to an upgrade.

**OR**

B) Edit and save files locally on client and then copy those files to the network share.

---

References
IBM Support page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ssg1S1004008

Samba Bugzilla page: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10774

Comment: Edit the answer and add the specific bits that would fix the problem.